# Elegantly put strings in same line

Tags: ruby

I need to `puts` a string like

```
puts "#{movie.title}, #{movie.imdb_rating.round(3)}, #{movie.imdb_ratings_count}"
```

So the output will be `Gone Girl, 8.23, 302532`

However, these are quite tedious since I always need to add `#{}` and `""`,

What is a good way to quick `puts`, without always adding `#{}` and `""`?

Comment: `puts [foo, bar, baz].join(' ')`?

Comment: @NigoroJr, yeah, and I can also abstract a small helper like that, and I'm still wondering more options.

Comment: Why do you want more options when you have a simple solution in front of you? Make the abstraction and be done with it.

Comment: Your expected format is not clear. Do you want to print the commas and spaces or not?

Comment: @sawa, I want the commas and spaces. Without them the strings will stick together, and will be hard to look at.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the extra information you've added as comments?  SO requires that the question be clear on its own, without having to read the comments.

Comment: Please address @Wayne's request.

Comment: @WayneConrad, I modified the question, I think its now much clearer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest constructing an array and using the [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join) method.

```
def printStrings do *strings
    strings.join(', ')
end

printStrings 'apple', 'banana', 'orange' #'apple, banana, orange'
```

Alternatively, you can utilize a special variable, called the output field separator, which you can access as `$,`. (Its default value is `nil`)

```
$, = ', '
print 'apple', 'banana', 'orange' #'apple, banana, orange'
$, = nil
```

This method is outlined in the docs for [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-print)

Comment: do I need to add a '\n' and the end of the `strings?`

Comment: If you want a new line at the end, then use `puts`, instead of `print`.

Answer (score 3):

It would make sense to add a method to the Movie class:

```
class Movie
  def to_desc
    "#@title, #{@imdb_rating.round(3)}, #@imdb_ratings_count"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

LukeP's answer is good if you want the same punctuation between each value but if you want something with a varying format, eg Gone Girl - 8.23, 302532, you can use ruby's % operator for string formating:

```
"%s - %s, %s" % [movie.title, movie.imdb_rating.round(3), movie.imdb_ratings_count]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's printing is solid but not amazing. Have you looked at the Awesome Print gem?

https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print

It's what I use to do elegant printing. It's a little unclear exactly how you're asking to format it, but this gems seems like it'll give you enough options to solve your problem.